# Envio de e-mail utilizando Gmail

Tags: delphi, envio-de-email, gmail, delphi-7, indy-10

Preciso de ajuda para enviar e-mail pelo **GMail** utilizando o **Indy10** e **Delphi 7**.
Creio que a versão do Delphi não deva importar tanto, e sim a versão do Indy certo?

Baixei a pouco o Indy10 pelo [indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/) e já instalei os componentes.

As Dll´s eu peguei do **pacote indy_openssl096.zip** que tem dentro do **SSL.zip**, nesse diretório.
E estou obtendo o seguinte erro:

> raised exception class EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary with message 'Could not load SSL library.'

Agora, ao baixar a versão **openssl-1.0.0l-i386-win32**, em [indy.fulgan.com/SSL/](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) passo a ter o seguinte erro:

> 'RCPT first. d8sm5855899vek.11 - gsmtp'.

Estou seguindo o seguinte exemplo do Marco Cantu [marcocantu.com/tips/oct06_gmail](http://www.marcocantu.com/tips/oct06_gmail.html).

Ou seja:

DFM dos componentes:

```delphi
object IdMsg: TIdSMTP
    OnStatus = IdSMTP1Status
    IOHandler = IdSSLSocket
    Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    Port = 587
    SASLMechanisms = <>
    UseTLS = utUseExplicitTLS
    Username = '****@gmail.com'
    Password = '****'
end
object IdSSLSocket: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
    Destination = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
    Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    MaxLineAction = maException
    Port = 587
    SSLOptions.Method = sslvTLSv1
    SSLOptions.Mode = sslmUnassigned
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
    OnStatusInfo = IdSSLSocketStatusInfo
end
```

Método para envio:

```delphi
procedure TMainForm.enviarButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdMsg.Clear;
  IdMsg.ClearBody;
  IdMsg.ClearHeader;

  IdMsg.From.Address := '****@gmail.com';
  IdMsg.From.Name := 'NOME';

  IdMsg.Body.Text := 'Data/Hora: ' + DateTimeToStr(Now);
  IdMsg.Body.Add('Teste');

  IdSmtp.Connect();
  IdSmtp.Send(IdMsg);
  IdSmtp.Disconnect;
end;
```

Então, afinal de contas, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Resposta derivada de: [Delphi 7 e gmail (conexão com autenticação)](http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/dica/6887)

O Gmail utiliza sistema de criptografia [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl), e para conectar nossa aplicação à ele, necessitamos de duas dll's especificas que seriam:

**libeay32.dll** e **ssleay32.dll**. ([o download delas pode ser encontrado aqui](http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/dica/6887/delphi-7-e-gmail-%28conex%C3%A3o-com-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29))

Após ter as  dll's em mãos, descompacte-as no diretório `C:\WINDOWS\System32`.

Insira no form os seguintes componentes: `IdSMTP` (paleta Indy Clients), `IdMessage`(paleta Indy Misc), `IdSSLIOHandlerSocket` (paleta Indy I/O Handlers) e um `Button`.

Para facilitar, renomeie o nome dos componentes para **SMTP**, **MSG** e **SSLSocket**, respectivamente.

Agora no **OnCreate** do form:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Begin
   with SMTP do
   begin
      AuthenticationType := atLogin;
      Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
      IOHandler := SSLSocket;
      Password := 'sua senha no gmail';
      Port := 465;
      Username := 'seulogin@gmail.com'; //não esqueça o @gmail.com!!
  end;
  SSLSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv2;
  SSLSocket.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
end;
```

Exemplo simples de uso com um botão:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with MSG do
  begin
    Body.Add('corpo da mensagem');
    From.Address := 'email do remetente'; //opcional
    From.Name := 'nome do remetente'; //opcional
    Recipients.Add;
    Recipients.Items[0].Address := 'shaokhann@gmail.com';
    Recipients.Items[0].Name := 'nome do destinatario'; //opcional
    Subject := 'assunto da mensagem';
  end;
  try
    SMTP.Connect();
    SMTP.Send(MSG);
    SMTP.Disconnect;
  except
    ShowMessage('Falha no envio!');
    exit;
  end;
  ShowMessage('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
end;
```

Comment: Eu acho que já tentei esse exemplo, mas vou testar..

Comment: Opa, estava meio ocupado mas vou testar agora.. mas a princípio, essa `IdSSLIOHandlerSocket` já não tem no indy 10. O que tenho aqui é o `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`. Vou ver se dar para fazer assim..

Comment: Estranho.. já mudei as opções da propriedade UseTSL do componente `IdSMTP`. Tentei com o `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` com as informações de host e porta e sem essas informações.. mas esta sempre travando no método `Connect`. O `AuthType` eu tive que deixar como `satDefault`. `SSLOptions.Method` e `Mode` eu deixei com o do exemplo, mas não deu também.

Comment: Vou levantar uma outra VM com o Delphi7 e Indy9 para ver se esse exemplo vai.. mas ainda acho que já testei esse.

Comment: Eu uso delphi 7 com Indy 9, e aqui funcionou certinho

Comment: Votado e +1. Fiz com o Indy 10 mesmo seguindo o exemplo mesmo que eu estava fazendo. Por incrível que pareça, eu estava esquecendo de informar a propriedade `Recipient`. Santo Deus!!! E muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Delphi 7 Indy 10, Envia email com  anexos.
// Testado! Funcionando!
//
// E não importa o que eu sofri.O que importa é que eu sobrevivi;
// Sarah Farias. https://www.letras.mus.br/mc-joe/1046127/

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 SMTP:TIdSMTP;
 MSG: TIdMessage;
 SSLSocket:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL; // <============== ***  indy 10
 attachFiles: TStringList;// <============== *** uses IdAttachmentFile
 i:integer;
begin

   // Criando objetos de conexão
   attachFiles:=TStringList.Create;
   SMTP:= TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
   MSG:= TIdMessage.Create(nil);
   SSLSocket:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil); //<==============

   // Formatando objeto de conexão (TIdSMTP)
   with SMTP do
   begin
      AuthType := atDefault;  //  <============== ***
      Host := TextServer.Text; //imap.gmail.com
      IOHandler := SSLSocket;

      Password := TextPassword.Text;// optei por tonar o meu gmail com senha propria para APPs com 16 dígitos.
                                    // Neste caso, o nome do executavel delphi (project1.exe) tem que estar cadastrado no gmail.
                                    // veja https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=pt-BR

      Port :=strtoint(Rd_Porta_Gmail.Items[Rd_Porta_Gmail.ItemIndex]);// usei a: 587
      Username := TextUser.Text; //endereço eletronico do remetente não esqueça o @gmail.com!!
      UseTLS:=utUseExplicitTLS;

   end;

   // Formatando objetos de conexão (TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL)
   with SSLSocket do
   begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23; //  <============== *** 23
      SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
      Destination :=  TextServer.Text+inttostr(SMTP.port);
      Host :=  TextServer.Text;
      Port := SMTP.port;
   end;

   //Buscando Caminhos dos Anexos'

   for i:=1 to ListBox_Envio.items.Count do
      attachFiles.Add(ListBox_Envio.items.Strings[i-1]);

   //Anexando....

   if(Assigned(attachFiles)) then begin
              for i := 1 to attachFiles.Count  do
              begin
                   if FileExists(attachFiles[i-1]) then
                   begin
                        TIdAttachmentFile.Create(msg.MessageParts,attachFiles[i-1]);
                        //showmessage('i='+inttostr(i)+' File Exists('+attachFiles[i-1]+')');
                   end
                   else
                        //showmessage('i='+inttostr(i)+' No Exists File('+attachFiles[i-1]+')');
                end;
            end;

   //showmessage('Anexou');


   // Compondo a mensagem total de envio
   with MSG do
   begin
      msg.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
      Body.Add('corpo da mensagem');
      From.Address := Textuser.text; //opcional
      From.Name := 'Nome Remetente'; //opcional
      Recipients.Add;
      Recipients.Items[0].Address := EdtPara.Text;
      Recipients.Items[0].Name := 'Nome Destinatário'; //opcional
      Subject := 'assunto da mensagem';
   end;


   // Efetivando o Envio:
   try
      showmessage('A conectar');
      SMTP.Connect();
      showmessage('Conectou');
      SMTP.Send(MSG);

      showmessage('Enviou');
      SMTP.Disconnect;
   except
      ShowMessage('Falha no envio!');
      exit;
   end;
   ShowMessage('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 SMTP:TIdSMTP;
 MSG: TIdMessage;
 SSLSocket:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
   SMTP:= TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
   MSG:= TIdMessage.Create(nil);
   SSLSocket:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

   with SMTP do
   begin
      AuthType := atDefault;//atLogin;//satDefault;//atLogin;atUserPass;
      Host := TextServer.Text;
      IOHandler := SSLSocket;
      Password := TextPassword.Text;
      Port :=strtoint(Rd_Porta_Gmail.Items[Rd_Porta_Gmail.ItemIndex]);
      Username := TextUser.Text; //não esqueça o @gmail.com!!
      UseTLS:=utUseExplicitTLS;//utUseImplicitTLS;
   end;
   with SSLSocket do
   begin
         SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
         SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
       //  OnStatusInfo := IdSSLSocketStatusInfo;
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
      Destination :=  TextServer.Text+inttostr(SMTP.port);
      Host :=  TextServer.Text;
      Port := SMTP.port;
   end;

   with MSG do
   begin
      msg.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
      Body.Add('corpo da mensagem');
      From.Address := 'Remetente@gmail.com; //opcional
      From.Name := 'Nome Remetente'; //opcional
      Recipients.Add;
      Recipients.Items[0].Address := EdtPara.Text;
      Recipients.Items[0].Name := 'Nome Destinatário'; //opcional
      Subject := 'assunto da mensagem';
   end;
   try
      showmessage('A conectar');

      SMTP.Connect();

      showmessage('Conectou');

      SMTP.Send(MSG);

      showmessage('Enviou');

      SMTP.Disconnect;

   except

      ShowMessage('Falha no envio!');

      exit;

   end;

   ShowMessage('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');

end;
```